# Which oAuth 2.0 flow can I use for server-to-server issuance of token?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, firebase-admin

Server-to-server token issuance requires that there's no html page requesting permissions in the flow. Server requesting the token is trusted party.

When I request oidc tokens from [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) or [AWS Federated Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html), what oauth 2.0 flows the SDKs use? I need to know this because I have my own oAuth server and I don't know which standard grant flow to use to directly issue oauth/oidc tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client credentials flow. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4

In OAuth 2.1 there will be only two recommended flow:

1. Authorization code flow with PKCE for user authentication
2. Client credentials flow for service to service authentication

See also:
https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials